# How do you send a ZIP file in the request body in SoapUI / ReadyAPI

Tags: soapui

I want to send a Zip file to an endpoint in the body of a REST request as a binary stream.

How can I accomplish this using SoapUI?

Simply adding the attachment to the tab does not include it in the body as it does for an HTTP Request

Comment: Have you tried [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html)?

Comment: The documentation does not detail sending of a file as a RAW stream in the body.   Hence the question raised on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out how this must be done.

When you add an attachment you can set its "Media Type" to match its "Content Type"

[image]

Your RAW request will then NOT display any content of the file (instead showing it is not available)

[image]